# lunch SSRS report programmatically using C# without opening the browser

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reportingservices-2005

my reports (.rdl file) dataset, lunche a procedure from sql server 2014.

i want to lunche the reports programmatically using C#

i refer to the following steps:

Add Web reference to the endpoints. 
Then we need to initialize the report by calling the LoadReport() method.
If the report contains parameters, we need to declare and populate an array of ParameterValue objects. 
Once the parameters are set up, we can call the SetExecutionParameters() method and pass them in rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(executionParams, "en-us").

i cannot do those steps because i take the parameters from the  dbo.ExecutionLogStorage  table

and its looks like:

```
=27%202%22016%2000%300%300&=26%210%22016%2000%300%300&__:=&__:=&__:=&__:=&__:=&___=96776&__:=&__:=&__:=&=%7%1%7........................
```

so its a problem to populate the array ParameterValue object (section 3)

BUT,  I have the url of the report, the url contains all the info about the report include the parameters, looks like:

http://ServerAdress/ReportServer_Name/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports/DealFile/DF_RPT11_AutonomyQuotaUtilization_Report&Year=2016&Summary=%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94:%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A02016&rc:Parameters=false

i tried to lunche the URL using the HttpClient, yet' it doesnt work.

using Fiddler i noticed that when im lunching the URL from the browser (and it lunches the report), there are few Requests and Responces on the backgroung before the report actually lunches.

guess a can not imitate browsers work....?

i need to run the report without opening the browser.

i tried in so many ways, and im **desperate** already...

anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReportExecution2005 endpoint to render report to HTML (or other) format and display it whenever you want. This obviously can be done without browser.
As I understand you're using [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) and you are on the right way. 
You can determine what parameters needed by opening report in browser. But, from URL you provided I can say that parameters setup should be like this:

```
var parameters = new ParameterValue[2];
parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Name = "Year";
parameters[0].Value = "2016";
parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
parameters[1].Name = "Summary";
parameters[1].Value = "שנה:   2016"; // ?!
```

The only thing is that decoded URL looks broken a bit, so you'd better check the report and its definition to know what the exact values for Summary parameter are.